# 403 Forbidden Error when doing Android Google Calendar Quickstart

Tags: android, api, calendar

I'm trying to add Google Calendar integration with my app.  I followed the Android quickstart guide here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android

I was having problems integrating this into my existing project, so I tried making a fresh project and copy and pasting the code.  However, I'm still getting this error:

```
403 Forbidden
{
"code": 403,
"errors": [
{
"domain": "usageLimits",
"message": "Access Not Configured. The API (Calendar API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
"reason": "accessNotConfigured",
"extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
}
],
"message": "Access Not Configured. The API (Calendar API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
}
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at com.gdosheriii.android.calendartest.ApiAsyncTask.getDataFromApi(ApiAsyncTask.java:72)
        at com.gdosheriii.android.calendartest.ApiAsyncTask.doInBackground(ApiAsyncTask.java:39)
        at com.gdosheriii.android.calendartest.ApiAsyncTask.doInBackground(ApiAsyncTask.java:19)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

What am I doing wrong?  I've been googling for an answer for the past two hours, but nothing seems to fix it.  Yes, I did create a client id inside the Google Developers Console.  I copied and pasted the package (com.gdosheriii.android.calendartest) and the SHA1 key. I have the Calendar API enabled.

What is the correct way to do it?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115420/access-not-configured-for-android-calendar-api

Comment: Don't think so.  I copy and pasted my package name directly and it matches the one in the dev console. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

you need to change application name in code de google quistart, you can do that by following this next steps:

```
private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
    private com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService = null;
    private Exception mLastError = null;

    public MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("YOUR APPLICATION NAME IN GOOGLE CONSOLE")
                .build();
    }
```

[image]